# Too much memory consumption while converting image between wpf and gdi+

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, bitmap

I am expecting too much memory consumption while converting an TransformedBitmap to a System.Drawing.Bitmap. 
The Image ist quite big with 7360x4912 pixel with a BGR32 Pixelformat which adds up to 144609280 bits ~ 138MB.

Initially I load the image from hard drive into a BitmapImage. Then rotate it with RotateTransform to end up with a final TransformedBitmap (WPF).

For Imageprocessing with EmguCV I will need System.Drawing.Bitmap. I convert the TransformedBitmap using the following function:

```
Private Function convertToBitmap(tb As TransformedBitmap) As System.Drawing.Bitmap

    Dim myBitmap As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(tb.PixelWidth, tb.PixelHeight, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    '140mb increase'

    Dim data As System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData =
        myBitmap.LockBits(New System.Drawing.Rectangle(System.Drawing.Point.Empty, myBitmap.Size),
                          System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)

    tb.CopyPixels(Int32Rect.Empty, data.Scan0, data.Height * data.Stride, data.Stride)
    'another 140MB increase'

    myBitmap.UnlockBits(data)

    Return myBitmap
End Function
```

The Loading of the TransformedBitmap takes about 140MB as expected. After converting the TransformedBitmap to a Bitmap using the mentioned function I can detect an increase of 276MB, which is exactly doubled the size of the image itself.

Do you have any clue of what I am missing? I want to keep the Transformed Bitmap as well as the converted Bitmap but nothing more.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Here is the Calling Code with some Comment on Memory:

```
Dim tb As New TransformedBitmap()

    ' Create the source to use as the tb source.
    Dim bi As New BitmapImage()
    bi.BeginInit()
    bi.UriSource = New Uri(Image_Path, UriKind.Absolute)
    bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad
    bi.EndInit()
    ' Properties must be set between BeginInit and EndInit calls.

    tb.BeginInit()
    tb.Source = bi

    ' Set image rotation.
    Dim transform As New RotateTransform(angle)
    tb.Transform = transform
    tb.EndInit()
    ' Set the Image source.
    imgChurch.Source = tb
    ' load the Image for OpenCV too
    _cvImage?.Dispose()
    'memory around 177MB
    Dim bmp As System.Drawing.Bitmap = convertToBitmap(tb) 'Memory is after 
    'Call about 454MB
    _cvImage = New CVImage(bmp)
    bmp.Dispose()
    GC.Collect()
```

CVImage Class is a wrapper for EmguCV lib.

```
public CVImage(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        var img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bmp);
        currentImg = img.Mat;
    }
```

Comment: show relevant parts of the calling code. on which lines of code do you break to take measurements? how do you measure memory allocation?

Comment: Small note... you say you're copying a `BGR32` bitmap, and yet you're using `Format32bppArgb` instead of `Format32bppRgb`. This will misinterpret padding bytes potentiallly containing junk or even 0-values as being alpha.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. After the conversion you have two bitmaps, each ~140MB. Doesn't that sum up to ~280MB?

Comment: @Clemens OP says he observes an _increase_ of 280MB, not total.

Comment: Ok, the question isn't very precise. Is the increase measured relative to the initial memory consumption, or relative to the point where the first 140MB are used? And has the garbage collector got a chance to run? OP should clarify that.

Comment: The garbage collector is quite lazy. It will not collect unless it has to collect. And if it only collects at application closure, that is the optimal case. If you allocated 2 Bitmaps of 140 MiB each, they will stay in memory. Even if not in use. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/286d8c7f-87ca-46b9-9608-2b559d7dc79f/garbage-collection-pros-and-limits?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: @Nyerguds: Thats correct. I will have a look. But it doesn´t explain why the doubled memory is used.

Comment: @Clemens: It is an increase. not total. See calling code comments.
I call GC.Collect afterwards, but it has no effect, so it seems to some reference left?

Comment: There are 3 copies of the bitmap around, BitmapImage, Image and CVImage.  So the memory usage increment is entirely normal.  You could at least get rid of one of them, the BitmapImage one looks unnecessary since you can also use Image.FromFile().  Also avoid having to fret over BitmapImage missing a Dispose() method.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thats correct. BitmapImage is only used to be displayed in the WPF Image Control. I just don´t get why there is this doubled memory increase in the specific line convertToBitmap(tb) . When creating the CVImage an additional normal increase of 140MB happens.

Comment: Doesn't `LockBits` copy the selected section into new memory to safely expose it? That would explain the increase... and it should go down again after `UnlockBits`.