# BitmapSource.CopyPixels does two copies?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, memory, bitmap

I´ve expected an unnormal increase in memory while copiing an image with BitmapSource.CopyPixels.

I´ve an image file pic.jpg with 2913*4744 pixels, so about 50MB with 32bpp in memory. It is loaded to a TransformedBitmap.
Then I try to convert it to a System.Drawing.Bitmap for image processing.

The strange thing happens when i call "tb.CopyPixels". I would expect an increase of memory of 50MB. Because the image, which has 50MB  is copied to a bytearray. But in fact I experience an increase of about 100MB, so exactly twice the amout of memory. Is there some kind of additional (intenal) Copy? What am I missing? How can I convert a Bitmapsource to a Bitmap with an increase of 50MB?

Thanks

Calling Code and Converting:

```
    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp;    
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TransformedBitmap tb = new TransformedBitmap();

        // Create the source to use as the tb source.
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.BeginInit();
        bi.UriSource = new Uri("pic.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
        bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bi.EndInit();
        //' Properties must be set between BeginInit and EndInit calls.

        tb.BeginInit();
        tb.Source = bi;

        //' Set image rotation.
        RotateTransform transform = new RotateTransform(90);
        tb.Transform = transform;
        tb.EndInit();
        //' Set the Image source.
        image.Source = tb;

        bmp = convertToBitmap(tb);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }


    private System.Drawing.Bitmap convertToBitmap(TransformedBitmap tb)
    {
        int stride = (tb.PixelWidth * (tb.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8));
        byte[] pixels = new byte[(tb.PixelHeight * stride)];

        tb.CopyPixels(pixels, stride, 0);  //<-- strange Memory increase of 
        //about 100MB. I expected 50MB (the image itself)

        System.Drawing.Bitmap myBitmap;

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pixels))
        {
            myBitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms);
        }
        return myBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: How much is it without the TransformedBitmap? And as a note, it doesn't makse sense to use TransformedBitmap as argument type of the convertToBitmap method. For flexibility, use BitmapSource instead.

Comment: On the next line, if you do `GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
GC.Collect();` does that impact memory usage? If so, by how much?

Comment: Didn't you ask [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49109248/too-much-memory-consumption-while-converting-image-between-wpf-and-gdi) two days ago?

Comment: Not sure how this would even work; the `Bitmap` constructor from stream doesn't expect raw pixel data, it expects _an image file._ It wouldn't know what to do with raw pixels without a width, height and pixel format anyway. Also, [the `Bitmap` class expects the stream to remain open until the image is disposed.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2)

Comment: @Nyerguds: You are right, that the bitmap is only usable, when the stream remains open. But thats not the point.This is just are short example to see the memory usage of the code.

Comment: @mjwills: It doesn´t helped. Same memory usage.

Comment: @Clemens: You are right when you say I should use the more general BitmapSource. Without rotating with TransformedBitmap, using BitmapImage bi  I expecting a normal increase in memory when copiing. So TransformedBitmap somehow makes an other copy  of the image. I try to investigate further on this. Thanks for your idea

Comment: btw, the memory use should actually increase when you initialize the byte array, at the line before the one you indicated. Did you check that?